# PHP script running on one web server, but fails to run on other home web server

Tags: php, apache, raspberry-pi

I'm currently new to web development and was doing some research on a safe way to store user's passwords. I stumbled upon a page about password hashing and adding salt. I downloaded the sample script and the test script (see below), but I can't get it to work on my home web server (raspberry pi Debian, Apache2 PHP5). The script DOES work on my actual web page hosted by a 3rd party hosting provider.

How come this script wont run on my own raspberry pi web server? Any help or thoughts will be greatly appreciated. If I forgot to mention some important info, feel free to ask.

The script runs up until "require_once('passwordhash.php');" Everything beneath doesn't run, so the first function "create_hash()" doesn't even work.

**EDIT:**
Error_reporting gives me this: Fatal error: Call to undefined function mcrypt_create_iv() in /var/www/hash.php on line 46

Test.php:

```
<?php
require_once('PasswordHash.php');
$hash = create_hash("foobar");
$result = validate_password("foobar", $hash);
if ($result)
{
    echo "Good";
}
else
{
    echo "Bad";
}
$result = validate_password("barfoo", $hash);
if ($result)
{
    echo "Bad";
}
else
{
    echo "Good";
}
echo "\n";
echo $hash;
?>
```

PasswordHash.php:

```
<?php

define("PBKDF2_HASH_ALGORITHM", "sha1");
define("PBKDF2_ITERATIONS", 1000);
define("PBKDF2_SALT_BYTES", 24);
define("PBKDF2_HASH_BYTES", 24);
define("HASH_SECTIONS", 4);
define("HASH_ALGORITHM_INDEX", 0);
define("HASH_ITERATION_INDEX", 1);
define("HASH_SALT_INDEX", 2);
define("HASH_PBKDF2_INDEX", 3);
function create_hash($password)
{
    // format: algorithm:iterations:salt:hash
    $salt = base64_encode(mcrypt_create_iv(PBKDF2_SALT_BYTES,                 MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM));
return PBKDF2_HASH_ALGORITHM . ":" . PBKDF2_ITERATIONS . ":" .  $salt . ":" .
    base64_encode(pbkdf2(
        PBKDF2_HASH_ALGORITHM,
        $password,
        base64_decode($salt),
        PBKDF2_ITERATIONS,
        PBKDF2_HASH_BYTES,
        true
    ));
}
function validate_password($password, $good_hash)
{
$params = explode(":", $good_hash);
if(count($params) < HASH_SECTIONS)
   return false;
$pbkdf2 = base64_decode($params[HASH_PBKDF2_INDEX]);
return slow_equals(
    $pbkdf2,
    pbkdf2(
        $params[HASH_ALGORITHM_INDEX],
        $password,
        base64_decode($params[HASH_SALT_INDEX]),
        (int)$params[HASH_ITERATION_INDEX],
        strlen($pbkdf2),
        true
    )
);
}
// Compares two strings $a and $b in length-constant time.
function slow_equals($a, $b)
{
$diff = strlen($a) ^ strlen($b);
for($i = 0; $i < strlen($a) && $i < strlen($b); $i++)
{
    $diff |= ord($a[$i]) ^ ord($b[$i]);
}
return $diff === 0;
}

function pbkdf2($algorithm, $password, $salt, $count, $key_length, $raw_output = false)
{
$algorithm = strtolower($algorithm);
if(!in_array($algorithm, hash_algos(), true))
    trigger_error('PBKDF2 ERROR: Invalid hash algorithm.', E_USER_ERROR);
if($count <= 0 || $key_length <= 0)
    trigger_error('PBKDF2 ERROR: Invalid parameters.', E_USER_ERROR);
if (function_exists("hash_pbkdf2")) {
    // The output length is in NIBBLES (4-bits) if $raw_output is false!
    if (!$raw_output) {
        $key_length = $key_length * 2;
    }
    return hash_pbkdf2($algorithm, $password, $salt, $count, $key_length, $raw_output);
}
$hash_length = strlen(hash($algorithm, "", true));
$block_count = ceil($key_length / $hash_length);
$output = "";
for($i = 1; $i <= $block_count; $i++) {
    // $i encoded as 4 bytes, big endian.
    $last = $salt . pack("N", $i);
    // first iteration
    $last = $xorsum = hash_hmac($algorithm, $last, $password, true);
    // perform the other $count - 1 iterations
    for ($j = 1; $j < $count; $j++) {
        $xorsum ^= ($last = hash_hmac($algorithm, $last, $password, true));
    }
    $output .= $xorsum;
}
if($raw_output)
    return substr($output, 0, $key_length);
else
    return bin2hex(substr($output, 0, $key_length));
}
?>
```

(script credits go to crackstation.net)

Comment: "Doesn't work" isn't sufficient for a diagnosis. Enable error_reporting to see anything, else add debug statements. (And you'd be better off switching to the built-in [`password_hash`](http://php.net/password_hash)/[`password_verify`](http://php.net/password_verify) anyway.)

Comment: Your Rasberry Pi might not include all the libraries necessary. Like @mario mentioned, please include all the debug information.

Comment: @mario I've added the error I received when I enabled error_reporting. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try installing Mcrypt for PHP.

Run in the terminal:
`sudo apt-get install php5-mcrypt`

You then need to enable the mcrypt extension, which can be done by some variant of:
`mv -i /etc/php5/conf.d/mcrypt.ini /etc/php5/mods-available/
php5enmod mcrypt`

You will then need to restart your webserver.

Comment: Running this in the terminal gives me the following: Unable to locate package php-mcrypt

Comment: Sorry, I missed out a '5', try again now.

Comment: Thanks, this works. Can you please explain why I had to add this package in order for this to work? Might be useful when I run into other issues on my own private server.

Comment: Some of the functions in your `PasswordHash.php` file are not included by default with a PHP install. Notably, any function beginning with `mcrypt` is from the mcrypt library (see http://php.net/manual/en/book.mcrypt.php), and won't run without having the library installed and enabled.

Comment: mcrypt_create_iv() is in php extension module called mcrypt. This extension is not by default compiled in to the base php instalation (like many other modules that are not used as often). In order to use functions from that extension you have to install it and enable it in php. And that is exacltly Tro's totorial does: Install module using apt-get: "sudo apt-get install php5-mcrypt" and enable it: "php5enmod mcrypt" (mv method is for older php builds). Same approach can be used for other modules: find module, find module's name in apt-get repo, install, enable, njoy ;)

Answer (score 0):

Please ensure that your PHP Version on the raspberry is compied with the --with-mcrypt parameter

See also http://php.net/manual/en/mcrypt.installation.php

> You need to compile PHP with the --with-mcrypt[=DIR] parameter to
>   enable this extension. DIR is the mcrypt install directory. Make sure
>   you compile libmcrypt with the option --disable-posix-threads .

Comment: You do not need to compile that in to php instalation as debian's apt-get allows you to install that package as an addition on to php. Since most people use managers like apt or yum, they do not have a choice of what is compiled in the instalation.